# Pegando informações de uma página HTML em C# (WebBrowser)

Tags: c#, html, navegador-de-internet

Estou tentando pegar uma informação de um site e estou com dificuldades em obter o resultado correto.

Basicamente, preciso pegar a versão do software no site:
https://www.computerbase.de/downloads/systemtools/all-in-one-runtimes/

O que me interessa é a linha:

```
<span class="download-version__version">2.4.6 <span class="german-flag">Deutsch</span></span>
```

Quero pegar os dados da classe "download-version__version" e não estou conseguindo...

Segue o código:

```cs
var htmlElement = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");

foreach(HtmlElement htmlEl in htmlElement)
{
    String nameStr = htmlEl.GetAttribute("class");
    if (nameStr != null && nameStr.Length != 0)
    {
        String contentStr = htmlEl.GetAttribute("download-version__version");
        MessageBox.Show(contentStr);
    }
```

Existe um método funcional?

Comment: Se trata do que? WindowsForms, uma aplicação console, wpf, web? E precisa ser com o WebBrowser? ele é um pouco lento e pesado para uma tarefa simples como esssa

Comment: Leandro, é WindowsForms e não crio o WebBrowser no formulário, crio o WebBrowser no código mesmo e apenas o redireciono para a página que eu informei.
Eu consigo pegar várias informações, mas não a informação dessa classe que está no código...
Não é necessário WebBrowser. Qualquer outra alternativa é bem-vinda.